# Can't set the value of text box to local storage value

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Ive tried a number of different examples to use on my own program. Im making a work day planner, so I have many text boxes and save buttons.

Heres the HTML so you can get an idea of the IDs ive used.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hour">
        <p class="time-block col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 ">8a</p>
      </div>
      <textarea class="description col-xl 10 col-lg-10  col-md-8 col-sm-8 " id="8am-text"></textarea>
      <button id="8am-btn" class="saveBtn col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

That is one of the 'time blocks' I have set up with the textbox and the save button that will be referenced in the JS portion.

```
$('#8am-btn').on('click', function() {
     var tb8 = $('#8am-text').val();
     localStorage.setItem('8am-text', tb8);
});
```

As it stands I can look in the local storage and successfully save the contents of the text-box. I just cant get any function to work to get the value of the local storage to corresponding text box so it remains after a page refresh.

An attempt i've tried:

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("8am-text")){
    tb8.value = "";
} else {
     tb8.value = localStorage.getItem('8am-text')
};
```

Thank you for all the potential help, im really pulling my hair out over this!

Comment: tb8.value = ""; ? 
have you defined this tb8 somewhere on the global scope ?

Answer (score 2):

You try this way.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hour">
        <p class="time-block col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 ">8a</p>
      </div>
      <textarea class="description col-xl 10 col-lg-10  col-md-8 col-sm-8 " id="8am-text"></textarea>
      <button id="8am-btn" class="saveBtn col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-2 col-sm-2">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
$('#8am-btn').on('click', function() {
    var tb8 = $('#8am-text').val();
    localStorage.setItem('8am-text', tb8);
});
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Store
  $("#8am-text").val(localStorage.getItem("8am-text"));
} else {
  $("#8am-text").val("Undefined");
}
```